# Subroutine not returning correct numerical values in assumed shape array due to index renaming in the main program

Tags: fortran, fortran90, dynamic-allocation

The argument of my fortran 95 subroutine is an assumed shape array with intent inout:

```
the_subroutine(my_argument)
real, dimension(:,:), intent(inout) :: my_argument
(...)
```

In the main program, I have an allocatable array. I allocate it **and also rename indexes**. Then I call the subroutine and pass that (correctly allocated) array to the subroutine:

```
allocate(the_array( 5:1005 , 5:1005 ))
call the_subroutine(my_argument=the_array)
```

The subroutine does certain calculations and fills the array with values. In **the very last line before the end of the subroutine**, I check a random value:

```
(...)
print*, my_argument(213,126) ! I get 2.873...
end subroutine the_subroutine
```

Then, in **the very first line after the subroutine call**, I check if the value has been correctly communicated by the subroutine to the outer world, but that is not the case:

```
call the_subroutine(my_argument=the_array)
print*, the_array(213,126) ! I get 3.798... A completely different value.
```

The problem arises from having re-indexed the array in the main program as:

```
allocate(the_array( 5:1005 , 5:1005 ))
```

where max_index - min_index = 1000-1, but the subroutine "sees" the array internally as if I had declared the normal way, i.e.:

```
allocate(the_array( 1:1000, 1:1000))
```

Or simply, allocate(the_array( 1000, 1000 ))

Therefore, the element (213,126) in the internal array is in another location as in the main program array. Is there any easy way out of this?

Comment: `my_argument` is assumed shape.  A procedure with assumed shape arguments requires an explicit interface in the calling scope.  Does `the_subroutine` have such an interface?

Comment: @IanH It is inside a module, so it does nor require any interface. I think.

Comment: Do you have INTENT(INOUT) on the subroutine? (You may need to show more code)

Comment: @Holmz Yes, I have it as you can see.

Comment: If it is ALLOCATABLE in the main, then should it also be ALLOCATABLE in the subroutine?

Comment: Using LBOUND, UBOUND and SHAPE in the subroutine can help with determining what is coming in is correct...

Comment: It does not need to be allocatable in the subroutine, but only assumed shape, I think. But please see the update in my question.

Comment: when you pass arrays as arguments to subroutines, the upper and lower bounds of the actual argument are not maintained in the call unless the lower bound is 1. However, when passing pointers, the lower and upper bounds are maintained. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38140951/fortran-subroutine-returning-wrong-values/38154225#38154225

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution.

First, if working in Fortran 2003 (or Fortran 95 with non-standard extensions), you may simply declare the assumed shape argument in the subroutine as ALLOCATABLE:

```
subroutine the_subroutine(my_argument)
real, dimension(:,:), allocatable, intent(inout) :: my_argument
```

Then the subroutine "sees" the renamed index correctly. However this is not allowed in the Fortran 95 standard.

In Fortran 95, the most elegant way I found for this is by making use of a pointer:

```
program example
implicit none
real, dimension(:,:), allocatable, target  :: the_array
real, dimension(:,:),              pointer :: the_pointer
[...]
allocate(the_array(5:1005,5:1005))
the_pointer => the_array
call the_subroutine(my_argument=the_pointer)
```

And in the subroutine:

```
subroutine the_subroutine(my_argument)
real, dimension(:,:), pointer :: my_argument
```

Then it works perfectly. Inside the subroutine, MY_ARGUMENT is treated exactly as if it was an assumed shape array.

Comment: When you add the pointer or allocatable attribute you get what is known as a deferred shape array.  By adding such an attribute you change the utility of the procedure - for example you are no longer able to pass array sections.  Adding pointer is also a reasonable way of telling the compilers optimiser that it doesn't have to do any work today.

Comment: @IanH Could you elaborate a bit more on "Adding pointer is also a reasonable way of telling the compilers optimiser that it doesn't have to do any work today."? - Also, I don't agree that you are no longer able to pass array sections. You can pass array sections by doing the same trick, just pointing to the array section, e.g.: the_pointer => the_array( : , 10:20 )

Answer (score 2):

The default lower bound for an assumed shape array is one.

If you want a different lower bound, then you need to declare the array dummy argument appropriately.

```
subroutine the_subroutine(my_argument)
  real, dimension(5:,5:), intent(inout) :: my_argument
!                 ^  ^
```

(The rules for the bounds of the dummy argument are different for deferred shape arrays - array dummy arguments which also have the POINTER or ALLOCATABLE attributes.)

Comment: Thanks. However, it is of not much value using an assumed shape array, if I have to know in advance the LBOUND value.

Answer (score 2):

use `lbound` to pass the bounds to the subroutine:

```
  implicit none
  real,allocatable:: x(:,:)
  allocate(x(5:10,5:10))
  call sub(x,lbound(x))
  write(*,*)'o',x(5,5)
  contains

  subroutine sub(x,lb)
  implicit none
  integer lb(2)
  real, dimension(lb(1):,lb(2):)::x
  x(5,5)=42.
  end subroutine
  end
```

> o 42.0000

Comment: Upvoted because that is a perfectly good solution. However if you pass several arguments and several lbound values it can be very messy.

Answer (score 0):

another approach to the problem: make the array a derived type and the subroutine a method of the type:

```
  module example
  implicit none
  type a
  real, allocatable::y(:,:)
  end type a
  contains
  subroutine sub(this)
  type(a)::this
  write(*,*)lbound(this%y)
  end subroutine
  end module

  program p
  use example
  implicit none
  type (a)  my_array
  allocate(my_array%y(5:6,7:8))
  call sub(my_array)
  deallocate(my_array%y)
  allocate(my_array%y(2:3,1:2))
  call sub(my_array)
  end
```

> 5 7
>
> 2 1

as you see now the subroutine automatically knows the correct dimensions. Obviously now the subroutine can only work with the derived type array.